# cvxpy: Code that works for default solver doesn't work for cp.GLPK_MI

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cvxpy

The following code works:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
ci = np.array([10,7,6,3])
x = cp.Variable(len(ci),boolean=True)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(ci@(2*x-1)))
problm = cp.Problem(objective)
_ = problm.solve()
```

However, if I pass a larger ci array, it doesn't work. Per recommendation [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/631), I want to try GLPK instead. So, I change the last line:

```
_ = problm.solve(solver=cp.GLPK_MI)
```

This leads to the following error:

```
SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['GLPK_MI']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.
```

Is it the way I'm specifying constraints works for the default solver but not for GLMK_MI?

Comment: You can only solve linear problems using GLPK, so GLPK sís imply not applicable to your problem.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK is correct. Try using Gurobi, CPLEX, or Mosek, if they are available to you.

Comment: @MarkLStone any reference on how much they cost?

Comment: MOSEK can be used for free for academics. Commercial pricing can be seen at https://www.mosek.com/sales/commercial-pricing/

Comment: CPLEX and Gurobi both have free academic licenses, which require verification that you are at a degree-granting academic institution.